# How to get the weight of the smallest path between two nodes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have a networkx graph in Python, with weighted edges. I want to get the weight of the smallest path between two nodes.

Currently, I am getting the nodes in the shortest path from the nx.shortest_path implementation, and then iterating through each pair and summing over the weights between each pair of node.

```
shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(G, source, destination, 'distance')

#function to iterate over each pair

import itertools
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

weightSum = 0
for adjPair in pairwise(shortest_path):
    weightSum = weightSum + G[adjPair[0]][adjPair[1]]['distance']
```

Is there a better (built-in) alternative to this?

Comment: What do you mean by _smallest path_? The path with the minimum number of edges? The path with the lowest weight?

Comment: I think the shortest path using Djikstra gives the path with the least weight. I want to know that weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You look for [`single_source_dijkstra`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.single_source_dijkstra.html):

```
from networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted import single_source_dijkstra

single_source_dijkstra(G,s,t)
```

---

**example**

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted import single_source_dijkstra

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=0.6)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=6)
G.add_edge('c', 'd', weight=0.1)
G.add_edge('c', 'e', weight=0.7)
G.add_edge('c', 'f', weight=0.9)
G.add_edge('a', 'd', weight=0.3)

single_source_dijkstra(G,'b','f')
```

**output**

```
(1.9, ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'f'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The networkx documentation has this page: [shortest paths](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html).

There are several options, but it looks like `shortest_path_length()` is what you want.

For clarity:

```
shortest_path = nx.shortest_path_length(G, source, destination, 'distance')
```